# Difficulty rendering a multipolygon from a GeoJSON using JQuery

Tags: leaflet, geojson, jquery, d3

I'm pulling polygon data (neighborhood boundaries in San Francisco) from an API on https://data.sfgov.org/Geographic-Locations-and-Boundaries/SF-Find-Neighborhoods/pty2-tcw4/data. While I made sure on my console that I'm indeed pulling the data, I am having trouble visualizing the layer as displayed on the original page.

I kept the [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mph6cdtj/3/) simple. I've tried different D3 methods but I keep running into dead ends, usually with a feature being undefined.

Comment: I don't understand your code; It is getting the data using `$.getJSON()`, but you are initilizing an empty GeoJSON using `var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that is retrieved from the API is not in GeoJSON format. The geometry attribute should be called **geometry** and not **the_geom** *(the_geom makes me think of an export from PostGIS)*.

So first you'll have to parse the JSON file into a proper GeoJSON file and then you can use something like:

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(jsonParsedToGeoJSON).addTo(map);
```